# Why does my page sometimes render in larger sizes?

Tags: html, css

Whenever I open my visual studio and go live sometime my page run correctly and sometime it give unexpected result with out changing a single dot in my code. I have shared my screen shots for understanding the issue please compare both ss and help me anyone please.

[image]

[image]

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) You should not just request a ready solution. SO is for helping solve specific errors, after you've shown your effort solving them

Answer (score 0):

You're using Chrome's mobile device emulator. Sometimes you need to refresh the page after enabling the emulator (or after live updates) so the page can render properly.

I prefer to have the dev tools on the side simply resize the panel to test various screen sizes while I work, without having the emulator enabled. This doesn't restrict screen *height*, but it shows width nicely without the problem you've encountered. I might then use the emulator to do final checks.